# kotlin: how to do ArrayList<int, object>

Tags: kotlin

I am new in Kotlin and i have the need for an mutable 2 dimensional list with different types.
What i need is best described as: ArrayList 
Can somebody give me a pointer on how to create something like this. 
Some background: the Int will be some groupingID so i can fast identify all objects in the list of a certain groupid. The groupid is NOT past of the object.

My workaround is to create this dummy object where i did add the groupid as a extra field but i do not really like it because i need to create a more of less duplicate object. I do not know if it makes a difference but i am building an android app in Kotlin.

Comment: Seems like it is better to use `Map` for your use case. You can map a group of objects to certain id and get this group using its id

Comment: Do the IDs start at 0?

Comment: The ID's are not a sequncial. it happens that the first is 0 but not every number is after that is present.
I will have a look at "Map" as i am not stuck on arrarList it was just my first idea.

Comment: Map or MutableMap will not work. the "key" value can only be used once where for me it is a groupingID which means there can be multiple objects with the same groupingId

Comment: @Michel your `Map`'s *keys* need to map to *values* that are a collection of some kind (`List`, `Set` etc) where you store everything associated with that grouping ID. That's the 2nd dimension, it would be the same if you just used `ArrayList`s (each element in the first list would contain another list). Kotlin even has some standard functions to do this, e.g. `groupBy` (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-grouping.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cactustictacs: all credits go to you but i cannot mark you answer is THE answer

> your Map's keys need to map to values that are a collection of some
> kind (List, Set etc) where you store everything associated with that
> grouping ID. That's the 2nd dimension, it would be the same if you
> just used ArrayLists (each element in the first list would contain
> another list). Kotlin even has some standard functions to do this,
> e.g. groupBy (see [kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-grouping.html](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-grouping.html)) –
> cactustictacs